# MS Access Run-time error '3011 displayed in one code but not in another

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error, ms-access-2016

Happy Anniversary and all the best for this community
I am trying to learn the use of DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet to export queries and charts to Excel
In my Database, I have two forms to export in each one a query to Excel and create a Chart
In each Form, the user selects a value in a textbox and an image is displayed on the Form
In Form frm_createxlstacked, the user picks two dates and click a command button to export the query to Excel and creates an xlClustered Chart. This VBA code works fine.

This is VBA code for createxlstacked

```
Private Sub cmbexpqry_stacked_Click()

Dim wb As Object
Dim xl As Object
Dim sExcelWB As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range
Dim ch As Object ''Excel.Chart
Dim mychart As ChartObject
Dim myMax, myMin As Double
Dim qry_createxlstacked As Object
Dim fullPhotoPath   As String

If IsNull(Me.cbxclstacked.Value) Then Exit Sub
Dim wb As Object, xl As Object, ch As Object, mychart As ChartObject
Dim fullPhotoPath   As String

fullPhotoPath = Add_PlotMap(Form_frm_createxlstacked.cbxclstacked.Value)
Set xl = CreateObject("excel.application")
On Error Resume Next
Kill TrailingSlash(CurrentProject.Path) & Form_frm_createxlstacked.cbxxlstacked.Value & "qry_createxlstacked.xlsx"
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0
sExcelWB = TrailingSlash(CurrentProject.Path) & "qry_createxlstacked.xlsx"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "qry_createxlstacked.xlsx", sExcelWB, True
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(sExcelWB)
Set ws = wb.Sheets("qry_createxlstacked.xlsx")
Set ch = ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
Set mychart = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
ws.Shapes.AddPicture fullPhotoPath, msoFalse, msoCTrue, r.Left, r.Top, 500, 250

With ch
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
    .SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 69
    .ChartArea.Height = 250
    .ChartArea.Width = 550
End with

wb.Save
xl.Visible = True
xl.UserControl = True
Set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

In Form frm_creategannt, the user picks two dates and click a command button to export query to Excel and creates an xlClustered Chart, but, VBA displays:
Run-time error '3011'. The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'qry_creategantt.xlsx'. Make sure that the object exists and that you...

This is VBA code

```
Private Sub cmbexpqry_gantt_Click()

If IsNull(Me.cmbexpqry_gantt) Then Exit Sub
Dim wb As Object
Dim xl As Object
Dim sExcelWB As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range
Dim ch As Object ''Excel.Chart
Dim mychart As ChartObject
Dim qry_creategantt As Object
Dim fullPhotoPath   As String

fullPhotoPath = Add_PlotMap(Form_frm_creategantt.cbxcreategantt.Value)
Set xl = CreateObject("excel.application")
On Error Resume Next
Kill TrailingSlash(CurrentProject.Path) & Form_frm_creategantt.cbxcreategantt.Value & "qry_creategantt.xlsx"
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0
sExcelWB = TrailingSlash(CurrentProject.Path) & "qry_creategantt.xlsx"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "qry_creategantt.xlsx", sExcelWB, True
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(sExcelWB)
Set ws = wb.Sheets("qry_creategantt.xlsx")
Set ch = ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
Set mychart = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
ws.Shapes.AddPicture fullPhotoPath, msoFalse, msoCTrue, r.Left, r.Top, 500, 250

With ch
    .ChartType = xlBarStacked
End With

wb.Save
xl.Visible = True
xl.UserControl = True
Set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing 

End Sub
```

The error is '3011' occurs in this line:
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, qry_creargantt.xlsx", sExcelWB, True

I compared one by one each line of codes. 
Also, I checked the Queries for each form.

I need to fix Run-time error '3011' to start testing VBA code to create Gantt Chart

In my opinion, I found no error, but I am stuck

I appreciate your reply, suggestion and effort in code with error.

Comment: And what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is occuring on the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` line as you indicate, then the error is very clear.

You have told Microsoft Access to run the query named `qry_creategantt.xlsx` (in order to export that data to Excel) and that query does not exist in your database.

Check the spelling of the Query in the Queries list, and in your code.  In your question above, where you restate that line of code as where the error occurs, you spelled the query name differently: `qry_creargantt.xlsx`.  Which spelling is correct?  That may be your problem.

Comment: Correct. I have to check carefully my spelling when writing code

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to call a query ".anything" the . is an illegal character in an access query name.

So carefully check the name of your query you are referring to. Because it isn't qry_creategantt.xlsx

Comment: I agree, but the OP claims that the code works in the first procedure, so I didn't check on the period being invalid, but you are absolutely correct, periods are not allow in object names.  Good catch.